# jquery selector multiple classes on set of <div>'s (contains one class, not the other)

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

This may be easier than what I've tried. I have a set of `<div>`'s such as `<div id="site-abc" .. "site-def">` and each has similar HTML content. The DIV's have multiple classes like `"ui-tabs-panel class2 ui-tabs-hide"`. One does not have ui-tabs-hide. That's what I need a selector for, and then from that I need to find unique text within that DIV that's within bingo!.

What's the right jQuery selector code for the following steps: A) find right `<div>` with `class="ui-tabs-panel"` but NOT CONTAINING `"ui-tabs-hide"`; B) take that selector result and find `('th.target2')` and get the `.text()`?

```
var tabs = $('#editors.not(.ui-tabs-hide'); 
var my_text = tabs.find('th.target2').text();

<div class="grid-editor">
    <div id="editors" class="ui-tabs">
        <div id="site-abc" class="ui-tabs-panel class2 ui-tabs-hide"> 
            //duplicates HTML like "site-ghi" including <th>bingo!</th>
        </div>
        <div id="site-def" class="ui-tabs-panel class2 ui-tabs-hide">
            //duplicates HTML like "site-ghi" including <th>bingo!</th>
        </div>
        <div id="site-ghi" class="ui-tabs-panel class2”>
            <table class=”my-table”>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="target1">abc1</th>
                        <th class="target2">bingo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. Use `:not` selector to omit the one you don't need.

```
var divs = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
```

I am not sure if this is related to the problem, but there is mistake in your selector statement as well.

```
var tabs = $('#editors.not(.ui-tabs-hide');
                                      //^ No Closing bracket
```

Comment: @DaveJ, I am sorry But I didn't understand what you were trying to say

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
var val = $('div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').find('th').filter(".target2").text();
alert(val);
```

See Here : http://jsfiddle.net/YxUfq/6/

Comment: Apologies... it was `<td class="target2">`, not `<td id="target1">` (corrected in code). Tried a # of the suggestions, but still no go. This is actually done with jquery tabs. Since nothing works, are there tab events / timing I need to account for. How do I account for default tab and later selection?     `var $tabs = $('#editors').tabs();`

    `$tabs.bind("tabselect", function(event, ui) {
    var val = ui.panel.find('th.target2').text();`
    `alert(val);`

I just started trying the tabs. Thought 1st approach was easiest.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_text = $('#target2', '.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').text();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hpyTk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = $('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
```

or

```
var divs = $('.ui-tabs-panel').not('.ui-tabs-hide');
```

And then find `target2` you can try this:

```
$('th#target2', divs).text();
```

According to your markup 'target2' is `id` not `class`. So correct will `th#target2`, not `th.target2`

Answer (score 0):

I think the coolest way to do is:

```
var text = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide) th.target2").text();
```

hope it helps

Comment: It's the other way around dude, the target goes before the context!

Comment: @adeneo Hey, thanks for notice! Already fixed it, thanks again :)